# Setting charset and collation on every query, is it neccessary and can I suppress it?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, character-encoding

I'm using Codeigniter and Mysql 5.1, the app queries the DB about 5k requests per hour and at the start of every query I get 
`SET NAMES 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci'`

This is adding signicant traffic. I have been asking on the codeigniter forum about this [My thread here...](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/184639/)

I have set every possible charset and collation (I think) setting to UTF8 and utf8_general_ci. database.php (Codeigniter DB connection settings) also has matching charset and collation settings for the client connections.
but I am still getting all these statements. Is their a way to suppress them?
I have converted the tables using alter table...convert to..

I am hoping someone on here with more MySql experience might have an idea.

```
[mysqld]
```

log = /tmp/mysql.log
default-character-set=utf8
default-collation=utf8_general_ci
collation-server= utf8_general_ci
character-set-server= utf8

[Screen shot from DB Utility showing server charsets and collations...](http://widget.askmoby.com/demo/images/db_settings.png)

Tks,
Owen.

Comment: Have you tried commenting out the char_set and dbcollat in config/database.php?

Answer (score 0):

The SET NAMES query sent before the actual query comes from CodeIgniter itself. If you do not want it, you need to configure the collation and character set in your MySQL server config file and then adjust the CI database class, like @Madmartigan suggested.

Comment: I have moved on from this but be back at it in the near future, thanks for the suggestion